# How to Change AccessibilityLabel on runtime in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, runtime, accessibility

I am showing a 30 min timer in my iOS application, I want to change the accessibilityLabel of the timer on runtime so that whenever the user taps it, the talkback will read the latest time. Right now the Label gets set to 30 min and whenever the user taps on the timer the talkback reads 30 min.

Comment: "I want to change the accessibilityLabel of the timer on runtime"  What is the accessibilityLabel of the timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

`UIAccessibility.post(.notification: .screenChanged, argument: timer.text)`

You want to use a .screenChanged notification because whenever the timer changes, the screen is changing as well. Your argument is the text that is changing.